# VBScript (.vbs) Produces Errors When Executed From A 2nd .vbs

Tags: arrays, csv, vbscript, onbase

We have a vendor who sends us CSV index files to be used with our OnBase document import software. If the CSV file was generated using one of our institutional forms, OnBase ingests them w/o error as we have set up corresponding Document Types that match the 1st delimited value in the CSV file. However, if the CSV file was generated using a vendor form, the 1st delimited value is slightly different and creates OnBase indexing errors. Our vendor uses this CSV format for many of their clients and have indicated it cannot be customized to match our current OnBase Document Types (w/o $$$).

I was tasked with identifying a workaround and found another institution using VBScript to create CSV index files before OnBase processing. After some collaboration, I was able to code a similar approach using VBScript. However, since we already receive index files, our approach identifies how many CSV files are in a target folder, via a loop opens each one, identifies the 1st delimited value within the CSV file, compares that value via a switch case method, updates the 1st delimited CSV value based on the switch case method, then saves the file, until the loop ends (loop value = # of files in target folder - 1...to account for the vbs file). When I click on the vbs file, it works like a charm!

Here is where the trouble begins. If I try and run the vbs file from another vbs file, the script produces errors: File not found. I included some debugging code, and I can see it correctly counts the number of files in the target folder, etc. When I thought it wasn't finding the target folder, I accounted for that by harcoding the path during testing. Even when I am sure it is finding the correct target folder, I'm receiving the same File Not Found error. If I double-click the exact same vbs file, it runs without error and all CSV files are correctly updated.

***Update*** @Ansgar Wiechers resolved the issue of finding and keeping the correct file path value. But, I'm still receiving a File Not Found error at line 163.

[image: Screenshot of error message.]

> Line 163
>   Char 1
>   Error: File Not Found
>   Code: 800A0035
>   Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

On a side note, I've also noticed that my vbs script will only run one time before you have to copy/paste a new instance in the target folder before running it again. Which leads me to think my loop never ended, so I included a debugging `MsgBox` that displays after the loop has ended (or think it has ended) and right before the `WScript.Quit` command. These are the last two lines in the script and the message box successfully displays. I'll include code below from both my vbs files.

VBScript file #1 (asterisks masking personal info):

```
Dim CurrentDirectory

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\*******\Desktop\ProVerify\Testing\ERROR_FILES\"
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\*******\Desktop\ProVerify\Testing\Old Source Files\VBScript_PV_Form_conversion.vbs", CurrentDirectory

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\*******\Desktop\ProVerify\Testing\ERROR_FILES\VBScript_PV_Form_conversion.vbs"
WshShell.Popup "VBS file will be deleted in 10 seconds...", 10
FSO.DeleteFile "C:\Users\*******\Desktop\ProVerify\Testing\ERROR_FILES\VBScript_PV_Form_conversion.vbs"

WScript.Quit
```

VBScript file #2 (in target folder with CSV files; removed switch case code for this post to save space):

```
' Declare vars
Dim intDebug, sFile, strDirectory, numFiles, sLine, aLine

intDebug = 1

' Find path of folder where script file resides & Set Object vars
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strDirectory = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)  

' Count number of files in folder 
numFiles = objFolder.Files.Count - 1

If intDebug = 1 Then
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Popup "File Count: " & numFiles, 2
    WshShell.Popup "File Path: " & strDirectory, 2
Else
End If

If numFiles <= 1 Then
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Popup "No Files to Process", 2
    WScript.Quit
Else
End If  

'Loop through each file in folder
For Each folderIdx In objFolder.Files
    Set oStream = folderIdx.OpenAsTextStream

    'Read file and capture first delimeted value
    sLine = oStream.ReadLine
    oStream.Close
    aLine = Split(sLine, ",")

    ' Compare delimeted value & update to OnBase DocType naming convention
    Select Case aLine(0)
        [*****case method here*****]
    End Select

    ' Create replacement delimited value
    sLine = ""

    For i = LBound(aLine) To UBound(aLine)
        sLine = sLine + aLine(i) + ","
    Next

    'Open file and replace updated delimeted value
    Set oStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderIdx.Name, 2)
    oStream.WriteLine Left(sLine, Len(sLine)-1) ' Remove comma from updated delimeted value
    oStream.Close
Next

'Reset Object vars
Set oStream = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing

If intDebug = 1 Then
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Popup "Conversion Complete", 2
Else
End If

WScript.Quit
```

In summary:

1. This code works fine (once) when I double-click; then a new instance needs to be copied/pasted into target folder before double-clicking will run the file again.
2. Code produces error when run via another vbs file, line 163, File Not Found.
3. I'm pretty sure this could be accomplished within OnBase, but our OnBase Sys Admin insists I am incorrect. The 51 OnBase User Guides referring to VBScipting over 1,500 times, tells me otherwise. That said, for now I've tasked with finding a solution outside of OnBase. Feel free to comment on this topic, too.

Comment: What is on line 163?

Comment: Assuming that line 163 is `Set oStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderIdx.Name, 2)` and you want to write the modified data back to the same file, you obviously need to change that statement in the same way as the statement where you open the file for reading (`Set oStream = folderIdx.OpenAsTextStream(2)`).

Comment: @Ansgar Thank you!! Changing the code during the write sequence to 'Set oStream = folderIdx.OpenAsTextStream (2)' did the trick!! Fantastic!! You are a Master...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors like the one you describe are usually caused by incorrect assumptions about the working directory of a script.

Your folder structure apparently looks somewhat like this (names shortended for brevity):

```
C:\base\folder
├── ERROR_FILES
│   ├── a.csv
│   ├── b.csv
:   :
│   └── second.vbs
└── first.vbs
```

When you double-click the script `second.vbs` the working directory is `C:\base\folder\ERROR_FILES`. However, when you double-click `first.vbs` the working directory is `C:\base\folder`. Invoking `C:\base\folder\ERROR_FILES\second.vbs` from there **DOES NOT** change the working directory for `second.vbs`.

Now let's take a look at the code in your second script:

```
strDirectory = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

'***********FOR TESTING ONLY**********************
If strDirectory = "C:\Users\*******\Desktop\ProVerify\Testing" Then
    strDirectory = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "\ERROR_FILES"
Else
End If
'***********FOR TESTING ONLY**********************

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

...

For Each folderIdx In objFolder.Files
    Set oStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderIdx.Name, 1)
    ...
Next
```

The "FOR TESTING ONLY" section kind of tries to account for the working directory difference by appending "\ERROR_FILES" to `strDirectory`, which allows you to enumerate the content of that folder. However, running `objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderIdx.Name, 1)` still attempts to open each file **from the current working directory**, which is still `C:\base\folder`.

To avoid this issue run `objFSO.OpenTextFile(folderIdx.Path)` or, better yet, use the object's `OpenAsTextStream` method. Also, when your script is residing in the same folder as your data files it's better to get the directory from the script path rather than appending a particular subfolder to the working directory (which may not be what you think it is).

Change the above code fragment to something like this, and it will do what you want:

```
strDirectory  = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

...

For Each folderIdx In objFolder.Files
    Set oStream = folderIdx.OpenAsTextStream
    ...
Next
```

Use the same approach when you open the file for writing:

```
Set oStream = folderIdx.OpenAsTextStream(2)
```

Comment: Thank you, A.W. Your solution to find the correct file path (target folder) works beautifully! I'm always amazed by the talent on this site. That said, I'm still receiving an error when the code looks for the files to open. Line 163, File Not Found. I'll try and attach a screenshot. I added more debug code to display the file path, and it's correct. Ideas? Can two vbs scripts be running at the same time?

Comment: @TheWOPR Yes, two VBScripts can absolutely run at the same time. Please edit your question and show your updated code as well as the complete error message.

Comment: Ansgar W-- Thank you!! Changing the code during the write sequence to 'Set oStream = folderIdx.OpenAsTextStream (2)' did the trick!! Fantastic!! You are a Master...